# Joomla: How to change the default datepicker?

Tags: joomla, datepicker

Currently Joomla is using mootools datepicker as it default datepicker, but my client don't like it and ask me to change it to another set.

However I can't find any settings in the administrator tool for me to change that.. or did I overlook it?

Anyone has any idea whether this can be done via settings or i need to change coding at the Joomla backend to achieve this?

Thanx

Comment: Where are you using the date picker ?

Comment: am using it in fabrik form...fabrik form gets the default datepicker from joomla

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic (this is not a programming question). Please support the [Joomla proposal on area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) if you'd like a dedicated Joomla equivalent of StackOverflow.

Comment: hmm.. in another perspective, it could be a programming question since it might involve changing the backend PHP code (I might be wrong since I don't know how to make it work now)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the admin or a parameter to change.  If you want to modify the type of calendar the component is using you'll have to re-code it.

The function that calls the calendar is in the com_fabrik/views/form/form.js
From their it's calling the libs/jscalendar/calendar.js which handles the object instantiation and contains the core calendar functions.

It would take time to replace it with something like jQuery UI's calendar (one of my personal favorites) and it's probably not worth it.  (At this point tell the "client" it'll cost a ton of money to do and they'll change their tune)

If they just don't like the look of it try modding the .css file libs/jscalendar/calendar-system.js